# strange case of assigning string to a variable in c++

Tags: c++, string

```c
1.  vector<string> cmdv=explode(" ","i am a string");
2.  std::string arg;
3.  char * args[10];
4.  for (i = 0; i < cmdv.size(); i++) {
5.      arg = std::string(cmdv[i]);
6.      if (cmdv[i][0] == '"') {
7.          //do some thing
8.      }
9.      args[i] = arg.c_str();;
10. }
11. args[i]='\0';
```

I expected the contents of `args` array `{"i","am","a","string"}` but `args` array is `{"am","a","string","string"}`

on debug i found that at line 6 in `if` clause when `cmdv[i][0]` is compared with `'"'`, `args[i-1]` is being replaced with contents of `arg`. I got baffled!

there is no problem with `explode` function. Its working good.

Comment: i dont understand how comparision operation is affecting the contents of args array. any comparision operation with cmdv at that point is changing the `args[i-1]`

Comment: I don't see why this deserved a downvote, except that perhaps it's more suited for stackoverflow than here perhaps.

Comment: please port it to stackoverflow then

Comment: @JohnB I knew that scope of the variable ends at that point. but it appeared to be working. and i am still baffled y the contents changing at comparison not while assigning new string to `arg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem :-

```
args[i] = arg.c_str();
```

The pointer returned by this is only valid while arg contains it's value and you alter arg each time through your loop. If you want to store a C style pointer to the string you'll need to make a copy of it, maybe something like :-

```
args[i] = strdup(arg.c_str());
```

But remember to free it. Plus there is probably a better way to achive what you want than using C style strings anyway

Comment: i didnt use strdup but i did `args[i]=string(arg.c_str()).c_str()` it didnt work. y? I'm assigning a new c type string r8?

Comment: You are creating a temporary string object there and then using c_str to get a pointer to the data stored inside it. The data it's pointing to will be destroyed at the end of the line when the temporary string is destructed. Because the data will likely still be in the memory location it may appear to work. Partly. Sometimes. Until that memory gets reused.

Comment: oh! thanq :D I knew that scope of the variable ends at that point. but it appeared to be working. and i am still baffled y the contents changing at comparison not while assigning new string to `arg`?

Comment: @neckTwi: Compiler optimization probably. You officially can't notice it any earlier. The debugger doesn't count.